# A regex matching text inside string with trailing newlines removed

Tags: java, regex

Hello I need to find regex that would get middle section of this text:

```
# Command // first line with symbol character 

First line of interest
Second line of interest
\n
Third line of interest
\n
\n // I am not interested in trailing new lines.
```

How could I get text starting with First line of interest and ending wint third line of interest? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String test = "# Command\n\nFirst line of interest\r\nSecond line of interest\n\r\nThird line of interest\r\n\n";
System.out.printf("%n>>%s<<%n", test);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?!#).+(?:[\r\n]+.+)*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
if (m.find())
{
  System.out.printf("%n>>%s<<%n", m.group());
}
```

output:

```
>># Command

First line of interest
Second line of interest

Third line of interest

<<
```

```
>>First line of interest
Second line of interest

Third line of interest<<
```

---

The match starts at the beginning (`^` in MULTILINE mode) of the first line that does not start with a hash symbol (`(?!#)`), but *does* contain characters other than line separators (`.+`, **not** `.*`).

`[\r\n]+` matches one or more line separators, whether they be the Unix (`\n`), DOS (`\r\n`), or older-Mac (`\r`) style of separator.  You should always be prepared to handle any or all of the different line separators, no matter what platform your code is running on.

`(?:[\r\n]+.+)*`, then, matches zero or more additional lines, without matching any trailing line separators.

Comment: +1 much more refined than mine plus good point about the line separators

Answer (score 3):

The example you've provided is very basic, I hope you can transfer this regex to your use case:

```
((?mi)First.*interest\b)
```

Explanation:

```
(
(?mi)    // Use DOTALL and MULTILINE mode
First    // First word you are interested in
.*       // Any character...
interest // ..up to the last word you are interested in
\b       // Word boundary to stop there
)
```

If the `(?mi)` isn't working, use the flags as documented in java.util.regex.Pattern.

To play around with regex, it is always good to have an editor who is showing you what the regex is matching, like this one: http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=# Command\\n\\n)[^\\n].*[^\\n](?=\\n*)", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

I wasn't sure how literal the text before the lines of interest was, so I hardcoded the positive lookbehind. You can modify it to your needs.